# Sort PHP Array Based on Number

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to get a Downloads page working. I get a build number and details from a file, and I want to sort the array with that build number, currently 0.0.2 is above 1.0.3, and it will always keep the build number as it ascends. You can see the page at http://tattyseal.com/files/zaet

```
<?php
    echo "<table border=0 style='text-align:left;border-spacing: 40px 0;'>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<img src='logoFile.png'/>";
    echo "<h2>Promotions</h2>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Promotion</th>";
    echo "<th>Version</th>";
    echo "<th>Minecraft</th>";
    echo "<th>Downloads</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>1.7.2-Recommend</td>";
    echo "<td>0.0.2</td>";
    echo "<td>1.7.2</td>";
    echo "<td>(<a href='http://ts.tattyseal.com:8080/job/Zaet/2/artifact/build/libs/Zaet-dev-0.0.2.jar'>Universal</a>) (<a href='http://ts.tattyseal.com:8080/job/Zaet/2/artifact/build/libs/Zaet-dev-0.0.2.jar'>Deobf</a>) (<a href='http://ts.tattyseal.com:8080/job/Zaet/2/artifact/build/libs/Zaet-src-0.0.2.jar'>Src</a>)";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";

    echo "<table border=0 style='text-align:left;border-spacing: 40px 0;'>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<h2>1.7.2 Downloads - Anything that is not Recommended can be unstable, there is a possibility of World Corruption</h2>";
    echo "<th>Version</th>";
    echo "<th>Minecraft</th>";
    echo "<th>Time</th>";
    echo "<th>Downloads</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $information = array();

    $iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('versions');
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iterator) as $filename => $file)
    {
        if (strpos($filename,'info') !== false)
        {
            array_push($information, file_get_contents($filename));
        }
    }

    sort($information);

    $information = array_reverse($information);

    $info = $information;

    $versions = array();

    foreach($info as $i)
    {
        $array = explode(",", $i);  

        foreach($array as $line)
        {           
            if(strpos($line, 'version') !== false)
            {
                if(strpos($line, 'mcversion') === false)
                {
                    $array2 = explode(": ", $line);

                    array_push($versions, $array2[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($information as $info)
    {
        $array = explode(",", $info);

        $mcversion = "";
        $version = "";
        $date = "";
        $build = "";

        foreach($array as $line)
        {           
            if(strpos($line, 'mcversion') !== false)
            {
                $array3 = explode(": ", $line);
                $mcversion = $array3[1];
            }

            if(strpos($line, 'version') !== false)
            {
                $array3 = explode(": ", $line);
                $version = $array3[1];
            }

            if(strpos($line, 'date') !== false)
            {
                $array3 = explode(": ", $line);
                $date = $array3[1];
            }

            if(strpos($line, 'build') !== false)
            {
                $array3 = explode(": ", $line);
                $build = $array3[1];
            }
        }

        echo "<tr><td>$version</td><td>$mcversion</td><td>$date</td><td>" . "(<a href='http://ts.tattyseal.com:8080/job/Zaet/$build/changes'>Changelog</a>) (<a href='http://ts.tattyseal.com:8080/job/Zaet/$build/artifact/build/libs/Zaet-dev-0.0.$build.jar'>Deobf</a>) (<a href='http://ts.tattyseal.com:8080/job/Zaet/$build/artifact/build/libs/Zaet-src-0.0.$build.jar'>Src</a>) (<a href='http://ts.tattyseal.com:8080/job/Zaet/$build/artifact/build/libs/Zaet-mod-0.0.$build.jar'>Universal</a>)</td></tr>";
    }

    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Define a comparator and use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: OP, please have a look at this [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I don't think the HTML part was necessary on your code.